Do I need a pull down resistor for an inverting Op Amp
I'm currently working on a circuit and I'm not too familiar with inverting Op-amps therefore I am asking for some help. Below is my circuit, it's the latter half of the circuit and just wondering if I need a pulldown resistor for the inverting Op-amp I have set up. The premise is the signal will come through the op-amp and get put into a capacitor delay that lasts 0.5 seconds due to the voltage across the capacitor being measured against the voltage divider and then once that threshold is hit, I need the inverting op-amp to output low into the 555 timer as it is set up in a monostable mode and need to get the triggers input signal below that of 1/3VCC in order for the 555 timer to output HIGH.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi there.  Your question is hard to read, there are too many words in one sentence.   Also, please refer to any components by their identifier rather than a description, eg: "U14" instead of  "inverter op amp".

Well, C1 would seem to be a problem. One end is at a fairly high impedance. Not so good. You may want to talk a little more about what you are trying to achieve, I suppose. It's possible you don't need the opamp since the 555 has a couple of useful thresholds already and the ability for a wide hysteresis (maybe too wide.) But I'm not sure I know why you are going to the trouble of an opamp or why the 555 won't work for you. So I'm lost on what to suggest, I guess.

Here is a circuit that "works" ...
Added a resistor at input "-" and changed some components.


If you change my R1 and C2 to yours, waveforms will be the same ... but "larger".

Do you have a gain equation for this?
